# Weird circumstances surrounding feedback interview after on-site interview

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, hiring-process

I recently had my on-site interview loop with a major international tech company where I was interviewing for several possible positions and I thought it went decently well. Later, I got a flurry of no-reply email notifications that looked like they want to hire me for a specific and identifiable position out of the potential positions we discussed and are scheduling an interview to discuss the terms of the offer with me.

Just in case, I decided to ask the recruiter whether that's what's going on. The recruiter replied by saying that those notifications were a glitch in the system, apologising, and suggesting we have an interview soon to discuss my feedback.

What do I take of this? Does this mean my chances of getting hired are good or are negative feedback interviews a common thing in such circumstances? Also, did I make a large mistake or faux pas by asking the recruiter whether they planned to discuss a job offer with me based on those notifications?

Comment: Just turn up to whatever meeting is arranged, it's not like you've got anything to lose at this point.

Comment: No way for us to do more than guess the cause. Probably was just a glitch. Probably no more significance than that. Ignore it, continue your job hunt, wait for them to schedule something, proceed from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do I take of this?

Nothing much. A glitch is a glitch and there doesn't seem anything happening here.

> Does this mean my chances of getting hired are good or are negative feedback interviews a common thing in such circumstances?

It doesn't mean anything, if was simply a system hiccup (which seems likely).

> Also, did I make a large mistake or faux pas by asking the recruiter whether they planned to discuss a job offer with me based on those notifications?

No. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to ask about.

Just ignore the notifications and proceed as if they didn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

I think the more interesting question is:

Does what was sent through interest you?

If the answer is 'yes' - then I would essentially let the recruiter know. Glitch or not, a hand has been shown and if you say 'What I saw, I liked, I'd like to proceed with that specific opportunity' - then that is within your right. The downside being that if they don't want you for that specific role, then gunning for it might put you out of the running.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I take of this?

It is definitely a glitch because no companies would send a flurry of **no-reply email** notifications that look like they want to hire you for a position.

In reality, if a company wants to hire you, the recruiters will send you a personal email or give you a phone call to discuss the hiring. They will never send you **no-reply email** to indicate that they may hire you.

---

> Does this mean my chances of getting hired are good or are negative feedback interviews a common thing in such circumstances?

Your chance is neither positive nor negative because it is a glitch.

---

> Also, did I make a large mistake or faux pas by asking the recruiter whether they planned to discuss a job offer with me based on those notifications?

No. You did not make any mistake.